# Is it OK to say something is "buried" in a webpage?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

What's the most proper way to express that some elements in a webpage are very undiscoverable? Can "buried in the page" be understood by most people?

Comment: Yes; that would be well understood.

Comment: [bury](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bury#bury__10)

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  It is a commonly used phrase which means that some text or concept can be found in a page (of text).  It also implies that alluded text is not easily found and is not highlighted or stands out in any form.

In some cases, it can have a similar meaning to that of "fine print" (which is used even when there is no difference in font size).

according to [this definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/buried):

"to consign to obscurity; cause to appear insignificant by assigning to an unimportant location, position, etc.:
Her name was buried in small print at the end of the book."

Answer (score 1):

"Buried in the page" can most likely be understood by wide audience regardless of internet knowledge. However, it would not be considered "proper"as the phrase is a metaphor.

Consider something like, "The content is not accessible in a straightforward/obvious/clear/simple way" or "The content can only be found through difficult/complicated/obscure methods". There are many synonyms/antonyms to convey the "easy" or "hard" of finding the content.

The "buried in the page" metaphor would work in a spoken context in an informal setting. The above phrasing would be "proper" if you are writing a paper or making a professional presentation.

Comment: Is "euphemism" the word you intended to use? "Buried in the webpage" does not sound euphemistic to me. Otherwise, you offered an excellent answer. http://literarydevices.net/euphemism/

Comment: I think so, as the definition of "buried" is to place or hide something underground. I suppose it could also be hyperbole.

Comment: I don't think this answer can be considered correct.  "Buried" is a dead metaphor, not a euphemism, and it's neither so informal nor so uncommon it can't be used in formal contexts.

Comment: Yes, I agree metaphor would be the way the describe the phrase. I do not agree that they can be used in formal context. Easily understood is good for a large audience who may have limited understanding of the subject, but if you are explaining something a professional setting (especially a paper) a level of knowledge is implied.

Answer (score 0):

*buried* would be understood by most people; you could also consider the phrases *hidden meat* and *mystery meat*

Mystery meat is discussed in the top answer [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/74842/what-is-the-name-of-the-anti-pattern-in-which-information-is-hidden-behind-inter)

[Mystery meat navigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystery_meat_navigation)

The phrase *mystery meat* seems to be first used by web designer Vincent Flanders in his book [Web Pages That Suck](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/078212187X).